# Running LWJGL on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, opengl, raspberry-pi, lwjgl, raspbian

I need to port something written in Java with LWJGL to a Raspberry. Im using Raspbian and tried oracles java version and some called "openjdk" or something like that.
With both versions I get this Exception:

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext.nLoadOpenGLLibrary()V

when creating the "Display".
I already searched for some solution, but they refer to OpenGLES and I did never use OpenGLES nor I found any download to use it.
I have no clue what to do and what information you might need, just comment if you need some more input.

**edit:**

Well you might want my current sourcecode too:

```
import java.io.File;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.Sys;
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.PixelFormat;


public class Main {
    private int fps;
    private long lastFPS, lastTime;

    Main() {
        createWindow();
        init2D();
        loop();
    }

    private void init2D() {
        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_PROJECTION);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();

        GL11.glOrtho(0, 500, 400, 0, -1, 1);

        GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);
        GL11.glLoadIdentity();
        GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        lastFPS = getTime();
        getDelta();
    }

    private long getTime() {
        return (Sys.getTime() * 1000) / Sys.getTimerResolution();
    }

    public void updateFPS() {
        if (getTime() - lastFPS > 1000) {
            Display.setTitle(Integer.toString(fps));
            fps = 0;
            lastFPS += 1000;
        }
        fps++;
    }

    private int getDelta() {
        long time = getTime();
        int delta = (int) (time - lastTime);
        lastTime = time;
        return delta;
    }

    private void loop() {
        float rot = 0;
        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()&&!Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
            GL11.glClear(GL11.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL11.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            GL11.glLoadIdentity();
            int x = Display.getDisplayMode().getWidth()/2;
            int y = Display.getDisplayMode().getHeight()/2;
            GL11.glTranslated(x, y, 0);
            GL11.glRotated(rot, 0, 0, 1);
            if(Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_SPACE)) {
                GL11.glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
            } else {
                GL11.glColor3f(1, 1, 1);
            }
            GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
            GL11.glVertex2d(-50, -50);
            GL11.glVertex2d(50, -50);
            GL11.glVertex2d(50, 50);
            GL11.glVertex2d(-50, 50);
            GL11.glEnd();
            rot+=0.05*getDelta();
            Display.update();
            updateFPS();
        }
    }

    private void createWindow() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(500, 400));
            Display.create();
        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        } // Window is created in this try-catch
        try {
            Assetloader.load();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        } // Load Assets
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File("native").getAbsolutePath());
        new Main();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raspberry Pi's only support OpenGL ES 2.0 and they're isn't any way around that.

OpenGL ES has no immediate mode rendering (glBegin, glVertex, glColor). You'll have to load your geometry into VBO's and render that way.

You'll also need to write basic shaders and pass your projection and modelview matrices in via glUniformMatrix.

Immediate mode rendering is pretty much only available on the desktop, iPhone's, Android's and Blackberry's use only OpenGL ES and pretty much any game console will use an API very similiar to OpenGL ES.

*Bottom line:* You'll need to ditch the immediate mode rendering and learn to use the ES spec.

These links should help...

http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/es_full_spec_2.0.25.pdf

http://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf

Comment: Thanks for you help already. I gonna read through those pdfs and tell you if it actually helped.

Comment: Those PDF's are the specs for OpenGL ES 2.0 and OpenGL Shading Language, it might be easier to find tutorials and only use the spec pdf's as reference when you get hung up on something.